# Prevent any Ajax XHR GETs returning 500 Error on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I have 4 charts in my page.

[image]

I simply make a AJAXGETs to 4 APIs, got data back,  and graph it.

**Issue : One of my Ajax is returning 500 error.**

---

I've tried to do all my action in the `.done()` like this

```
var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/zero-rate'});
ajax.done(function (data) {
    //do stuffs ... 
});
```

But that doesn't seem to help.

---

When I refresh my page, under `Network Tab` I always see one of these ajax XHR GET is red(500) as this image below.

[image]

---

**Note :**

- It's not reproducable all the time.
- Sometimes, 2 returns errors.
- Sometimes, different GETs return error.
- Sometimes, all of those GETs working fine without error.

---

How do I prevent these errors and make sure all those GETs work before start rendering ?

Should I start looking into **JS promise** or jQuery **Defered** Object ?

I don't know much about those yet.

---

Entire Code

```
@extends('layouts.internal.master')
@section('content')

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div id="gragh_ubb_0_rate"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div id="gragh_ubb_hour"></div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div id="gragh_ubb_day"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div id="graph_month"></div>
  </div>
</div>



@stop


{{-- Page-specific scripts --}}
@section('pagescripts')


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


  //constants

  var graph_ubb_configs = {

    "subcaption": "",
    "yaxisname": "Bandwidth (KB)",
    "formatnumberscale": "1",
    "plotgradientcolor": "#0075c2",
    "palettecolors": "#03A9F4",
    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
    "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
    "showplotborder": "0",
    "showvalues": "0",
    "labeldisplay": "WRAP",
    "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
    "suseroundedges": "1",
    "showcanvasborder": "0",
    "canvasborderalpha": "0",
    "defaultnumberscale": "KB",
    "showborder": "0",
    "captionFontSize": "14",
    "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
    "baseFont": "Roboto",
    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
    "subcaptionFontSize": "12",
    "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
    "subcaptionFontColor": "#08c",
  };

  var t_line = [{"line": [{"startvalue": '{{ $total_bytes }}', "color": "#F44336", "valueOnRight": "1", "tooltext": "Limit", "displayvalue": "Threshold", "dashed": "1"} ] } ];

  var c_time = '{{ $hour }}';


  /*================================
  =            Zero Rate           =
  ================================*/
  // 1-31 days


  var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/zero-rate'});
  ajax.done(function (data) {

    console.log('%c Zero Rate API ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(data);

    if(data != null){

      var up_link = data.zero_rate_vlan['up_bytes']/1000000;
      var down_link = data.zero_rate_vlan['down_bytes']/1000000;


      console.log(up_link);
      console.log(down_link);




      graph_ubb_configs.caption = "Zero Rated Traffic";
      graph_ubb_configs.subcaption = data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y;
      graph_ubb_configs.xaxisname = "Bandwidth";


      var gragh_ubb_0_rate = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "bar2d",
        "renderAt": "gragh_ubb_0_rate",
        "width": "100%",
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource": {
          "chart": graph_ubb_configs,
          "data":[{"label": "Uplink","value":parseFloat(up_link)}, {"label": "Downlink","value":parseFloat(down_link)}],
          "trendlines": t_line

        }
      });

      gragh_ubb_0_rate.render();

      console.log('%c ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ', 'color: #0075c2');

    }





  });








  var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/hour'});

  ajax.done(function (data) {

    // delete data.hour_p_ubb[0];

    console.log('%c HOUR API ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(data);


    var hour = [];

    for(var i=0; i<24; i++) {

      var time = i%12;

      if(time == 0){
        time = 12;
      }

      if(i<12){
        var am = 'AM';
      }else{
        var am = 'PM';
      }

      var val = data.hour_p_ubb[i]['up_bytes']/1000000 + data.hour_p_ubb[i]['down_bytes']/1000000;
      var object = {"label":time + ' ' + am,"value": + val};
      hour[i] = object;

    }

    console.log('%c HOUR Value ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hour));

    graph_ubb_configs.caption = "Daily Network Usage";
    graph_ubb_configs.subcaption = data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y + ' ( '+data.time+' )';
    graph_ubb_configs.xaxisname = "Hours of Day";

    var gragh_ubb_hour = new FusionCharts({
      "type": "column2d",
      "renderAt": "gragh_ubb_hour",
      "width": "100%",
      "dataFormat": "json",
      "dataSource": {
        "chart": graph_ubb_configs,
        "data":hour,
        // "trendlines": t_line

      }
    });


    gragh_ubb_hour.render();

    console.log('%c ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ', 'color: #0075c2');

  });



  /*=============================
  =            DAY            =
  =============================*/
  // 1-31 days


  var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/day'});
  ajax.done(function (data) {

    console.log('%c DAY API ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(data);

    // var day = [];
    var labels = [];
    var values = [];

    for(var i=0; i<data.day_p_ubb.length; i++) {

      var up_link = parseFloat(data.day_p_ubb[i]['up_bytes'])/1000000;
      var down_link = parseFloat(data.day_p_ubb[i]['down_bytes'])/1000000;
      var val = parseFloat(up_link+down_link);
      var c_d = data.d;

      if(i == 0){
        var c_val = 0;
      }else{

        if(i <= c_d ){
          var c_val = parseFloat(c_val) + parseFloat(val);
        }else{
          var c_val = '';
        }

      }

      var label_object = {"label":String(i+1)};
      var data_object = {"value":parseFloat(c_val)};

      labels[i] = label_object;
      values[i] = data_object;

    }

    graph_ubb_configs.caption = "Monthly Network Usage";
    graph_ubb_configs.subcaption = data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y;
    graph_ubb_configs.xaxisname = "Days of Month";


    var gragh_ubb_day = new FusionCharts({
      "type": "msline",
      "renderAt": "gragh_ubb_day",
      "width": "100%",
      "dataFormat": "json",
      "dataSource": {
        "chart": graph_ubb_configs,
        "categories": [{"category": labels } ], "dataset": [{"data": values } ],
        "trendlines": t_line

      }
    });

    gragh_ubb_day.render();

    console.log('%c ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ', 'color: #0075c2');


  });







  /*============================
  =            Month           =
  ============================*/

  var ajax = $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/month'});
  ajax.done(function (data) {

    console.log('%c MONTH API ', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(data);

    var month = [];
    for(var i=0; i<12; i++) {

      var val = data.month_p_ubb[i]['up_bytes']/1000000 + data.month_p_ubb[i]['down_bytes']/1000000;

      if(i == 0){
        var object = {"label":'January',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 1){
        var object = {"label":'Febuary',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 2){
        var object = {"label":'March',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 3){
        var object = {"label":'April',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 4){
        var object = {"label":'May',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 5){
        var object = {"label":'June',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 6){
        var object = {"label":'July',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 7){
        var object = {"label":'August',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 8){
        var object = {"label":'September',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 9){
        var object = {"label":'October',"value": val};
      }else if(i == 10){
        var object = {"label":'November',"value": val};
      }else{
        var object = {"label":'December',"value": val};
      }

      month[i] = object;
    }

    console.log('%c Month Value', 'background: #222; color: #bada55');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(month));


    graph_ubb_configs.caption = "Yearly Network Usage";
    graph_ubb_configs.subcaption = data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y;
    graph_ubb_configs.xaxisname = "Months of Year";


    var graph_month = new FusionCharts({
      "type": "column2d",
      "renderAt": "graph_month",
      "width": "100%",
      "dataFormat": "json",
      "dataSource": {
        "chart": graph_ubb_configs,
        "data":month,
        "trendlines": t_line
      }
    });

    graph_month.render();

    console.log('%c ------------------------------------------------------------------------ ', 'color: #0075c2');

  });

</script>


@stop
```

Comment: code 500 mean  Internal Server Error

Comment: Unless you are passing bad parameters to the Ajax call, a 500 error needs to be fixed on the server, not on the client.  You should check the parameters to make sure what you are sending is what is intended and is proper for the API.

Comment: @Mostafa : I know that, but how do I prevent that ? Is the way I did my AJAX is bad or wrong ? Please kindly advise.

Comment: It's either bad parameters you're sending with the ajax call or it's entirely a server error and there's nothing you can do to fix it on the client.

Comment: @jfriend00 : Great hint, I'll looking in my controller if there anything wrong in there ... but the 500 is not consistent. Sometimes, all of them works, sometimes 2 of them works, sometime only 1 of them have issue.

Comment: Inconsistent could easily be a server problem too.

Comment: Hmm... But the API is reachable fine at all time, and will return API data back as always, if I would have visit it via the URL or cURL via Terminal, so why AJAX is the only one with issues ? Do u know ?

Comment: Servers can have concurrency issues/bugs that cause intermittent problems.  Happens all the time.

Comment: As written, your four ajax calls are made in parallel. Try - at least for diagnosis - making them sequentially.

Comment: How do u suggest the best practice for that Ajax sequentially?? Place the other 3 in the .done() of the first one?? Or I start looking into promise or defer?

Comment: Probably better to write an answer ...

Comment: What what is the 500 error message? What is the server saying is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might need to make the ajax call sequentially instead of in-parallel.

First, wrap your four parts in `function() {...}` and return `jqXHR` from each.

```
function make_zero_rate_graph() {
    /*================================
    =            Zero Rate           =
    ==================================*/
    // 1-31 days
    return $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/zero-rate'}).then(function(data) {
        if(data) {
            var gragh_ubb_0_rate = new FusionCharts({
                'type': 'bar2d',
                'renderAt': 'gragh_ubb_0_rate',
                'width': '100%',
                'dataFormat': 'json',
                'dataSource': {
                    'chart': $.extend({}, graph_ubb_configs, {
                        'caption': 'Zero Rated Traffic',
                        'subcaption': [data.m, data.d, data.y].join('/'),
                        'xaxisname': 'Bandwidth'
                    }),
                    'data': [
                        { 'label': 'Uplink', 'value': +data.zero_rate_vlan.up_bytes / 1000000 }, 
                        { 'label': 'Downlink', 'value': +data.zero_rate_vlan.down_bytes / 1000000 }
                    ],
                    'trendlines': t_line
                }
            });
            gragh_ubb_0_rate.render();
        }
    });
}

function make_hour_graph() {
    /*===========================
    =            Hour           =
    =============================*/
    return $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/hour'}).then(function(data) {
        var gragh_ubb_hour = new FusionCharts({
            'type': 'column2d',
            'renderAt': 'gragh_ubb_hour',
            'width': '100%',
            'dataFormat': 'json',
            'dataSource': {
                'chart': $.extend({}, graph_ubb_configs, {
                    'caption': 'Daily Network Usage',
                    'subcaption': data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y + ' ( '+data.time+' )',
                    'xaxisname': 'Hours of Day'
                }),
                'data': data.hour_p_ubb.slice(0, 24).map(function(item, i) {
                    return {
                        'label': (i%12 || 12) + ' ' + ((i<12)?'AM':'PM'),
                        'value': (+item.up_bytes + +item.down_bytes) / 1000000
                    });
                }),
                // 'trendlines': t_line
            }
        });
        gragh_ubb_hour.render();
    });
}

function make_day_graph() {
    /*===========================
    =            DAY            =
    =============================*/
    // 1-31 days
    return $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/day'}).then(function (data) {
        var c_val = 0;
        var gragh_ubb_day = new FusionCharts({
            'type': 'msline',
            'renderAt': 'gragh_ubb_day',
            'width': '100%',
            'dataFormat': 'json',
            'dataSource': {
                'chart': $.extend({}, graph_ubb_configs, {
                    'caption': 'Monthly Network Usage',
                    'subcaption': data.m + '/' + data.d + '/' + data.y,
                    'xaxisname': 'Days of Month'
                }),
                'categories': [{
                    'category': data.day_p_ubb.map(function(_, i) {
                        return { 'label': String(i+1) };
                    })
                }],
                'dataset': [{
                    'data': data.day_p_ubb.map(function(item, i) {
                        c_val += (i > 0 && i <= data.d) ? ((+item.up_bytes + +item.down_bytes) / 1000000) : 0;
                        return { 'value': c_val };
                    })
                }],
                'trendlines': t_line
            }
        });
        gragh_ubb_day.render();
    });
}

function make_month_graph() {
    /*============================
    =            Month           =
    ==============================*/
    var months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November','December'];
    return $.ajax({url: '/api/timebase/'+'{{ $cpe_mac }}/month'}).then(function (data) {
        var graph_month = new FusionCharts({
            'type': 'column2d',
            'renderAt': 'graph_month',
            'width': '100%',
            'dataFormat': 'json',
            'dataSource': {
                'chart': $.extend({}, graph_ubb_configs, {
                    'caption': 'Yearly Network Usage',
                    'subcaption': [data.m, data.d, data.y].join('/'),
                    'xaxisname': 'Months of Year'
                }),
                'data': data.month_p_ubb.slice(0,12).map(function(data, i) {
                    return {
                        'label': months[i],
                        'value': (+data.up_bytes + +data.down_bytes) / 1000000
                    };
                }),
                'trendlines': t_line
            }
        });
        graph_month.render();
    });
}
```

*Code within the functions is tidied but not tested*

With those functions in place, calling in sequence is trivial :

```
// List the functions in an array 
var fns = [ make_zero_rate_graph, make_hour_graph, make_day_graph, make_month_graph ];

// And build a then() chain by reducing the array,
// see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises/5917/#t=201612121359154320486
fns.reduce(function(jqPromise, fn) {
    return jqPromise.then(fn);
}, $.when());
```